# Is it past a calculated time & date?

Tags: php, date, time

I've got to do a check if it's already past a certain time and date.
Normally this would be easy for me, but the time that has to be checked is half an hour prior to the time I actually get from the database.

Let's say the database says: "2014-01-16" and "20:00". In this case I'd have to check if it's already past "21:30" on the 16th of januari 2014.

I have some code working for me now but it only says it's past that date if both the date and time have been passed (let's say it's the day after so it's obviously passed, it also has to be past 21:30 for it to say so).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Get the date today and date of the event to check if the customer can still buy tickets
$dateToday = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
// $details['Datum'] == 2014-01-15
$dateStart = strtotime($details['Datum']);

// Check if it's half an hour before the event starts, if so: don't sell tickets
$timeNow = strtotime(date('H:i'));
// $details['BeginTijd'] == 20:00
$substrStart = substr($details['BeginTijd'], 0, 5);
$startTimeHalfHour = strtotime($substrStart) - 1800;

if($timeNow > $startTimeHalfHour && $dateToday >= $dateStart) {
    // It's past the given time limit
    $tooLate = true;
} else {
    // There's still time
    $tooLate = false;
}
```

As you can see, it requires both the time and date to be past the given limits. In this example, if it's past the 15th it should set $tooLate to true, or if it's past 21:30 on the 15th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strtotime("+30 minutes")` to get the time in 30 minutes.

So assuming that $startTime is the time (unix time) the event starts, you could do

```
$current = strtotime("+30 minutes");

if($current > $startTime){
$tooLate = true;
}
else{
$tooLate = false;
}
```

By the way, lines like `$dateToday = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));` don't make much sense. Writing `$dateToday = time();` has the same result.

`strtotime()` gives you a a Unix timestamp (number of seconds since 1970). `time()` also does.

To generate `$startTime` (the time the show starts at), you should take the full date and time string (eg. `2014-01-15 18:10:00`) and pass it to `strtotime`. It will convert it to a Unix time.

If what you want is the time of the event minus 30 minutes, you could write:

```
$maxTime = strtotime("-30 minutes",$startTime); //where $startTime is the start time of the event, in Unix time.
```

Source: https://www.php.net/strtotime

Comment: But I need the time for when the event starts - 30 minutes, not the current time +30. What would startTime be in this case?

Comment: Well the end result is the same. You can either check the current time + 30 minutes, or the event time minus 30. The logic is the same. But if you really want event+30, I've added that to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly :). I had the old $dateToday = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); because I'm not very good at date/time calculations so I looked up how to's online. Code can get messy when you work using different resources.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to convert DateTime strings to Unix timestamps for comparisons like this. This can be done with the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. Example:

```
$dateToday = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-16 20:00');
// Adds an hour to the date.
$date->modify('+ 1 hour');

if ($dateToday > $date) {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Alright but this doesn't really solve my problem. I still need to take off 30 minutes from the limit date.

Comment: A Unix timestamp denotes the time in seconds (starting in 1970). Therefore you can easily manipulate it by adding 1800 seconds to it. Or you can use DateTime's `modify` method.

Comment: You don't need to convert to timestamps. DateTime objects are directly comparable so this will work:- `if ($dateToday > $date) {//do stuff}`